# NPX hardhat compile failing

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am following the OpenZeppelin docs for deploying a smart contract. but when i run

```
npx hardhat compile
```

i get this error

> ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
> --> contracts/Transactions.sol:5:1:

I have installed the openzepellin contracts library and i have checked manually to see if the file i am requiring in my contract exists. It does. I import it like this

```
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

NB trying to import with this line

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

results in my code editor throwing this warning (the compile command also fails)

> Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed. I had to copy the entire @openzeppelin folder from node_modules and paste in the root directory of my contracts folder.

Comment: that's an awful fix

Comment: Thanks. youve been very helpful

Comment: Post a small reproduction repo on Github. It's hard to help based on the little info you've provided. My bet is that your folder structure is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

change your import statement to

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

and then check

Comment: I have edited my question. I started with this, but it gave me an error from the code editor

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it like this because i found this from the **OpenZeppelin Documentation**

- https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access#Ownable

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I started with this, but it gave me an error from the code editor